# toggle switch switching too fast keyboard module python

Tags: python, keyboard, logic, toggle, infinite

I'm having a problem creating a proper toggle switch.

```py
import keyboard

x=0
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        if x == 0:
            x = 1
            print('on')
        elif x == 1:
            x=0
            print('off')
```

This code works fine, but it switches way too fast. I also have a game running in the background so I can't just wait. I also don't want to open a new core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with, not sure if it helps or not since there is still unnecessary waiting for `keyboard.is_pressed` to eventually return `False`. But it does only trigger each toggled state once. I would suggest trying a better maintained and well documented module than `keyboard` personally.

```
import keyboard

on = False
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('A'):
        while keyboard.is_pressed('A'):
            pass
        if on:
            print("on")
        elif not on:
            print("off")
        on = not on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a delay before it switches, you may want to consider using the `time.sleep(t)` method, which essentially takes in an argument `t` for how long in seconds the execution is to be delayed.

For example, if you want to add in a delay of a fourth of a second:

```
import keyboard
import time

x=0
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
       if x == 0:
           x = 1
           time.sleep(0.25)
           print('on')
       elif x == 1:
           x=0
           time.sleep(0.25)
           print('off')
```

Comment: this is a working solution but I have a game to run in the background and that would drop frames and delay keyboard input once the key is pressed. thank you for helping though